# How to write code in Swift file that executes when module is loaded?

Tags: swift

Say I have a registry defined inside of a module called Registry:

```
class Registry {
  static let sharedInstance = Registry()
  registerImplementation(implementation: AnyClass, forInterface interface: Protocol) {...}
  implementationForInterface(interface: Protocol) -> AnyClass {...}
}
```

And an API and implementation respectively in the modules FooServiceAPI and FooServiceImplementation respectively.

```
// In FooServiceAPI target:
protocol FooService {
  ...
}

// In FooServiceImplementation target:
import FooServiceAPI
import Registry

// This line causes an error saying that code cannot be executed at the top level.
Registry.sharedInstance.registerInterface(FooService, forImplementation: FooServiceImplementation)

class FooServiceImplementation: FooService {
  ...
}
```

I would like FooServiceImplementation to be automatically registered in the Registry for the FooServiceAPI interface, so that other classes can use them like so:

```
import Registry
import FooServiceAPI

class Bar {
  func baz() {
    let fooService: FooService = Registry.sharedInstance.implementationForInterface(FooService)
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I accomplish this without forcing the application to individually register the implementations in the AppDelegate? Thanks!

Comment: as much as I know and searched (had the same problem), this is not possible. static variables in swift act as lazy variables.